# using TypeScript and Sails.js is giving issues, TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sails.js

Converted my Sails.js app to using TypeScript and when I try to hit my previous routes I'm getting errors around "TypeError: object is not a function".

I created a controller using a Class and re-wrote my functions in TypeScript.  At the end I instantiated my new controller doing

```
var controller = new TestController();
export = controller;
```

I'm not understanding what I did wrong here.  I referenced the work done on http://alexclavelle.blogspot.com/2015/03/using-sailsjs-with-typescript.html?showComment=1435617822375

Still nothing...I'm guessing it is something with the es5 code that gets generated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

```
var controller = new TestController();
export = controller;
```

the runtime cannot do `controller()`.

## Fix:

```
var controller = () => new TestController();
export = controller;
```

Comment: I think this got me farther...though now my routes are all messed up.  All of my routes are giving this error in console on sails.js/node.js startup

    error: Ignored attempt to bind route (/) to unknown controller.action :: index.findthis